# Make my own front-mounted headphone/mic connector

Tags: windows-7, audio, cable, av-cable

I have a computer built from hand-me-down parts that has onboard sound.  I have a set of speakers and a pair of headphones I would like to use, and currently I have to dig around behind the computer to switch between them.  The motherboard has pinouts for front-mounted headphone and mic connectors that, when connected, will automatically turn off the speakers and route all sound input and output through the front-mounted ports.  Unfortunately, the case doesn't have connectors.

Can I make my own front-mounted connectors?  How much would it cost, and from where can I buy the necessary parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not need "parts" at all, depending on your motherboard. If you have open drive bays available, the [Front Panel Controllers](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=11&name=Controller-Panels) section at NewEgg rocks. One very promising unit would be the [Startech 35BAYPANELBK Black 3.5" Drive Bay Multi-Port Panel](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811996006) ($27 US as of today.)

This is way easier than having a shop do custom work, or drilling anything into your case. And there are **lots** of different panels and configurations available.

Comment: A few months later, and I finally ended up buying something similar to this.  It works great, I just lack all the proper USB headers.

Answer (score 1):

while i'm pretty sure that it is possible to drill 2 holes into the case and fit a headphone and mic socket, why not not  just installing a cheap secondary sound card?

advantage: you can use speakers and headset simultaneously for different sources rather than switching between.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can salvage it from a second hand computer shop or you could ask a local computer repair guy they always have spares, the rates would depend on how well you can bargain